# Injecting global ActionFilter to existing ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

For an ASP.NET MVC COSTS application, I need to intercept all action calls. I only have access to modify the `global.asax` and `Web.config` files since it's already compiled and I have no access to the source code. Am I out of luck on injecting a global action filter to it?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't really do anything other than decompile and do some funky stuff that way.

Comment: You would probably be able to add an HTTP Module, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve as to how useful that would be.

Comment: The COTS application has no authentication but I need to add a custom authentication to it, not integrated windows authentication.

Comment: If you want auth, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960019/http-module-authentication

Comment: Like you said, i may have to roll my auth http module. I don't see any other ways to get around this.