# IIS HTTP Basic auth for specific URL

Tags: iis, basic-authentication

I want to restrict access using HTTP Basic Auth for a specific path so that someone who visits /www/private will be prompted with the authentication but not /www/public , /www/public/dashboard, ....

note: "private", "public", "dashboard", etc are not folders, but url rewrite

My current webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
<location path="mysite/www/private">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="mysite/www">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I also enabled basic auth and anonymous authorization in IIS Manager
[image]

However this does not work - it never prompts for authorization

Comment: didn't quite understand  " note: "private", "public", "dashboard", etc are not folders, but url rewrite " .I do not see any rewrite rule which rewrites to private .Could you give the URLs you are working with ?

Comment: I'm using nette framework, which handles this. I'm sorry I don't know specifics. But the point is that those urls are not folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS URLRewrite module rewrites the request before the authentication kicks in so with your current rewrite rule,this is not possible.

Exceprts from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

> The URL Rewrite module is a native code module that plugs into the
>   request-processing pipeline at the Pre-begin Request or Begin Request
>   stages, and then evaluates the requested URL path by using a set of
>   rewrite rules. Each rewrite rule analyzes the URL path and, if all the
>   rule conditions are met, changes the original path to a new path.
>   After all the rules have been evaluated, the URL Rewrite module
>   produces a final URL path that is used for the request through the
>   remainder of the IIS pipeline processing. This means that the handler
>   selection in the IIS pipeline is made based on the rewritten URL that
>   is produced by the URL Rewrite module.

Your rewrite rule is in such a way that it rewrites any path which is not to a static file to index.php. Rest of the IIS pipeline sees the path as index.php. You have to implement your authentication inside index.php.Or you can easily write a simple IIS module,this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809717/how-to-implement-basic-http-authentication-with-the-vs-debug-server) talks about it. You have to add little bit more logic to check the URL(if contains www/private) and send 401 etc.